# Oracle change value in record based on math with subset of other records

Tags: sql, oracle

**TLDR**: How do I update 2+ values in a table based on math with other records in the same table?

**Long and ugly details below**

I have a set of records (actually several, so this is just one of them), which have string and number values.  Say something like this:

**Example Source Data**

```
Name      HrValue  DayValue   IndName         IndHrValue   IndDayValue  IntPct    seq   main
BHight     286       1033     MiscBHight                                 .55      10
BHight                        BC               659          2033                  20    False
ATL                           Sinsel             8            34                  20    False
ATL        789       3922     MiscATL                                    .95      20    True
PSC        127       832      MiscPSC                                    .01      30
```

I need to do some math on *some* of them, the numbers of one affect the others.  In this case, the three with the same seq number.

I need to insert the IndHrValue and IndDayValue for the record where main = 'True' and the seq are the same, based on the HrValue of the main minus the sum of any IndHrValues that are not main; insert the main IndDayValue based on the DayValue minus the sum of any IndDayValues that are not main.

So, I need to get the numbers 659, 8 and 2033, 34 (where main=False), in the set where seq are the same, and then use that to insert 789-(659+8) for IndHrValue and 3922-(2033+34) for IndDayValue (where main=True).  So the table would be updated to look like this:

**Example Source Data after update**

```
Name      HrValue  DayValue   IndName         IndHrValue   IndDayValue  IntPct    seq   main
BHight     286       1033     MiscBHight                                 .55      10
BHight                        BC               659          2033                  20    False
ATL                           Sinsel             8            34                  20    False
ATL        789       3922     MiscATL          138          1923         .95      20    True
PSC        127       832      MiscPSC                                    .01      30
```

And I'm not sure how to wrap my head around doing this.  I can add other fields, if necessary.  I can write this data to a temporary table or put it in a cursor in a procedure.  I can create tables indicating rules for what goes with what.  (I'll need to do that, because sometimes I need to deal with the HrValue of other records as well as the IndHrValue(s).)

Essentially, if I have a set of two (or more) records, how do I change the data in one based on the value in the other?

Currently, I've written the data to a temp table, and I can pull out just the three records with the following query:

```
select *
from MT_TMP_GRP_TBL tbl
where tbl.seq in (
    select seq from (
        select seq, count(*)
        from MT_TMP_GRP_TBL
        group by seq
        having count(*) > 1
    )
)
;
```

That, of course, doesn't work when I now have more sets that also need to be grouped and updated.  My non-fake table also has a date/time field as well as a sequence, and together they make a unique set.  (so, that sequence 20 will be repeated for each hour, but I think I can make it complex to fit this scenario, once I can understand a solution to the simplified one I'm showing here.)

And I think I can then do an update on the record that is true based on the record(s) that is/are false...  Except.  I just can't figure out how.

Maybe I could write all the main=False to another table, and then pull out each set in that table, and use that when I insert those where main=True?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih - those first two tables are an example: source and then expected result.  Let me label them.

Comment: "TLDR"?? Do you even know what that means? Hint: it makes absolutely no sense in the original post of a thread.